# delete user email account in SSH server using python or awk?

Tags: python, bash, ssh

my task is to delete user's email account and all the stuff associated with this account in SSH server. I have the super user right. The thing is: this needs to be done for hundreds of user accounts. So, it would be much more better if it can be done with the help of a small script (python or awk) instead of doing this manually. I have two years' experiences with python, while on the other hand, I don't have too much experiences with awk. So, I was wondering, which language fits my task better? and I would be really appreciated if you can point to several references. Thank you in advanced for your time and attention.

Comment: Language recommendations are off-topic for [so]. See [help/on-topic]

Comment: awk is for manipulating text. What you want to do is not just manipulating text so you can exclude that from the options you're considering and I'm going to delete that tag now.

Answer (score 0):

why would you like to solve such a task with awk, when you have no experience with awk? awk is great, but maybe pretty haed to read and complex, depending on what you want to achieve. With experience in python, you should be able to solve the issue with python. Using python your solution should be better, safer and nicer to read.

Comment: Well, I thought awk is easy to learn. Do you have similar experiences of this using Python? Any references or links would be great.

Comment: awk is powerful, but to master it is very hard. Easy to learn? I don't think so. Furthermore interacting with maybe a database backend and maniupulating maildirs or something like that is definetly better solvable using python.

Comment: I see. Thank you a lot, olisch. Could you provide some referencing links or something like that? I do not know where to get started. I'm currently reading http://www.phys.hawaii.edu/~idlab/bronson/projects/erle-robotics-python-gitbook-free.pdf.

Comment: @olisch awk is ridiculously easy to learn because it's such a small, simple language (very similar to C and every other Algol-based language) and has just the subset of language constructs needed to manipulate text. All of the other tools/languages discussed so far are VASTLY more complicated than awk because their scope is more than just manipulating text (which is ALL awk is for). Awk is just not the right tool for this particular job.